# Polymer's index of ids after dom-if

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

In my Polymer app based Polymer Starter Kit, I've added basic authentication and switch between login and app views via  `<template is="dom-if" if="[[authenticated]]" restamp>` element.

After successful authentication, the page should be updated, stamping the elements on the page. What I discovered that app.js can no longer find any of the elements by element id, like this: `app.$$('#headerPanelMain').scrollToTop(true);`. In fact, none of the queries with `$$()` work at all, returning `null`.
It seems as if `$$()` can't penetrate anything that is stamped with `dom-if` even though Polymer docs says it should: [Polymer - Local DOM - Automatic node finding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html#node-finding)

I'm on Polymer 1.4 now.

Comment: What value does the `authenticated` have when you query for the elements? `dom-if="false"` removes the elements from the DOM therefore they can't be found.

Comment: `authenticated` is definitely true at this point. The problem with `$$()` happens when I'm already trying to navigate between pages and routing logic asks pages to scroll to the top. The login screen is hidden at this point (also with `dom-if` but with `!authenticated` condition).